# fromEvent not working, native event binding is

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-fromevent, streamable.com

I'm building a [video-player library for angular](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player). Currently working on a Streamable integration.

I've recreated the situation in a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wc9wme?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html,types%2Fplayerjs%2Findex.d.ts,tsconfig.json&title=Angular%20Starter), where you can see a `console.warn` for `player.on('ready', ...)` but not for `fromEvent(player, 'ready').subscribe(...)`

```
const player = new playerjs.Player(iframe);

player.on('ready', () => console.warn('player.on(ready)'));
fromEvent(player, 'ready').subscribe(() => console.warn('fromEvent ready'));
```

Does anyone know why `fromEvent` doesn't work in this situation?

Similar examples (also using `on`):

- [Example 1](https://github.com/rrtheonlyone/XVariables/blob/master/client1/src/players/Streamable.js#L23)
- [Example 2](https://github.com/cookpete/react-player/blob/master/src/players/Streamable.js#L26)

I have to note that the same does actually work for [Vidyard](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-vidyard-player/src/lib/extensions.ts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use the `fromEventPattern` function, which allows you to specify custom add and remove handler functions.

Example;

```
const addHandler = (handler) => player.on('ready', handler);
const removeHandler = (handler) => player.off('ready', handler);

fromEventPattern(addHandler, removeHandler).subscribe(() => console.warn('fromEventPattern ready'));
```

From the above, I use `addHandler` to adds a handler for the 'ready' event, and `removeHandler` that removes a handler. `fromEventPattern` uses these functions to create an Observable that emits events whenever the 'ready' event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

`ready` is not a standard event, `on` is not a standard `addEventListener`.

You're likely looking for `fromEvent(player.elem, 'load')`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the same does seem to work for [Vidyard](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-vidyard-player/src/lib/extensions.ts)